# How to explicitly require no authentication in a certain route, in node.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, path, routes, reset-password

I'm relatively new to node.js and I'm pretty much just a beginner :/.
I'm currently working on a reset password function (currently without tokens) on my application which works.
However, my reset passwords links always have the user's email at the end of the link ( eg: "http://localhost:3000/auth/reset/limtrum3@gmail.com" ).

On the other hand, I have an ensure_auth function that blocks access to all pages unless the req.path is specified, like this:

```
async function ensure_auth(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated() || req.path === "/index" || req.path === "/" || req.path === "/auth/login" || req.path === "/auth/register" || req.path === "/auth/forget" || req.path === "/auth/reset") {
    return next();
}
else {
    flashMessage(res, 'danger', 'Warning!!! Please Login to access the page', 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle', true);

    return res.redirect("/auth/login");
}
```

}

Because of this, my reset password page requires the user to logged in before the page can be accessed.
I've tried to set "/auth/reset" along with many other paths but it doesn't work.
Is it possible to have a req.path that works for all pages that have "/auth/reset", regardless of what comes after it, or is there another way to go about doing this?

Sorry for my poor wordings and thank you in advance! :D

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Use

```
req.path.startsWith("path")
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp